# How to resize my app for every iPhone

Tags: ios, resize

I'm a beginner app developer and just finished creating my first soundboard app, the only problem is that the layout of the app fits on an iPhone 6s but when i change the simulator to any other iPhone the app doesn't fit on the screen the positioning of it changes and some buttons are left out, how do i make the size of the app fit on every iPhone?

Comment: Your app is resized automatically -- the issue is that the components positions and sizes are hardcoded -- when they need to respond to their size --Look for autolayout tutorials: https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Answer (score 0):

because you did not write code related to layout fitting.
there will be two ways you can auto layout your UI.
firstly,calculate the frame of each UI component and put those code into layOutSubviews.

secondly,using autoLayout is wise choice and I would recommend you Masonry which is a third-party autoLayout framework if you develop under Objective-C.

best regards & thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to to accomplish this task:-

1. Auto Sizing, Old way to make UI for different screen size this
   will use the struct and spring framework to create UI.
2. Multiple StoryBoard, You can create a separate storyboard for
       different device. Simple but never recommend to use this way as it
       will make application more complex and make application heavy, you
       have to update every storyboard when ever you have to make changes
       in UI
3. Programmatically, you can also create your UI
       programmatically and calculate there frame and set constraint to
       your UI
4. Auto layout "Recommended" , can create a single
       storyboard and and apply auto layout constraint to you view on
       storyboard and programmatically.

here are some link on auto layout
https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/
https://www.weheartswift.com/auto-layout-101/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Auto layouts and size classes for this.

**Auto layouts:**

Auto Layout dynamically calculates the size and position of all the views in your view hierarchy, based on constraints placed on those views. For example, you can constrain a button so that it is horizontally centered with an Image view and so that the button’s top edge always remains 8 points below the image’s bottom. If the image view’s size or position changes, the button’s position automatically adjusts to match.

This constraint-based approach to design allows you to build user interfaces that dynamically respond to both internal and external changes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

**Size classes:**

Use size classes to enable a storyboard or xib file to work with all available screen sizes. This enables the user interface of your app to work on any iOS device.

With size classes, a storyboard or xib file can be used for any available screen area. You build your interface as it will look in most sizes, then update only the parts that need to change when the available screen size changes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html